# How can I use @RolesAllowed in Java EE 6.0

Tags: jax-rs, java-ee-6

I'm using jax-rs 1.1 (as this JavaEE 6.0) and want a standard way to manage permission for my resources. I've tried this:

```
@Path("/public/login/")
@Stateless
@RolesAllowed("ADMIN")
public class LoginResource implements Serializable {

    @POST
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response login(Usuario usuario) {
       ....
    }

}
```

But it appears to have no effect. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your application may be missing security constraints in `web.xml` and in that case it is ignoring any security annotations.

Try to add the following to your `web.xml`:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>all</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admins</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-role>
    <role-name>admins</role-name>
</security-role>
```